# NSPredicate Validate: a-z, 0-9 and underline

Tags: objective-c

I want to only allow a-z, 0-9 and _(underline), but its not working properly.

```
NSString *test = @"name_test09"; // should be valid
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"[a-z0-9_]"];

if ([predicate evaluateWithObject:test] == NO) {
    // not validated
} else {
    // validated
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be.

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@", @"[a-z][0-9]_"];
```

**MY EDITED:**

```
NSString *s =@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890_";
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES[c] %@",s];
```

**or**

```
NSString *myRegex = @"[a-z0-9_]*"; 
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", myRegex]; 
BOOL valid = [myTest evaluateWithObject: test];
if (valid)
{
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: @LucianoNascimento- try with my latest update , may be mistake of *, you forget to put at end of you formation :)

Comment: Yeah this answer sucks.  What is "SELF MATCHES"?  Why is that there?  I am getting not validated too.